# Ignore all files except one or more files from a specific file type in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Identical question to [gitignore: Ignore all files in folder hierarchy except one specific filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803689/gitignore-ignore-all-files-in-folder-hierachy-except-one-specific-filetype), but for Mercurial.

I want `.hgignore` to ignore all files except one or more files from a specific file type, for instance only allow files of the `*.java` and `*.class` file type to be tracked, in the current directory as well as sub directories.

For example, in the following directory:

```
A.java
a.txt
a.png
A.class
B/C.java
B/G/H/h.png
B/C.class
D/E/F.java
```

I only want the following files to be included (including the structure of the directories):

```
A.java
A.class
B/C.java
B/C.class
D/E/F.java
```

(it does not matter if the directory containing `h.png` will be created or not.)

I've tried applying and changing the same principles as mentioned in the question above (but for Mercurial instead), as well as trying to apply principles from the question [How can I ignore all directories except one using .hgignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637496/how-can-i-ignore-all-directories-except-one-using-hgignore), without any luck.

EDIT: I tried the following with the mentioned directory tree above

```
$ hg stat
? A.class
? A.java
? B/C.class
? B/C.java
? B/G/H/h.png
? D/E/F.java
? a.png
? a.txt
$ hg add -I "**.{class, java}"
adding A.class
adding A.java
adding B/C.class
adding B/C.java
adding D/E/F.java
```

which gave me the wanted result. How do I create a `.hgignore` or config file that applies the `-I "**.{class, java}"` for each `add` or `commit` (and similar queries)?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
syntax: regexp
.*\.(?!java$|class$)
```

or better yet:

```
syntax: regexp
.*\.(?!java$|.*\.java$|class$|.*\.class$)
```

which will also match weird stuff like "a..java" or "a.java.java".

EDIT: Here's a revised solution incorporating Søren's tips and some further tweaking on my part. I hope the false positives e.g. that something like "ajava" or "java" didn't get ignored, are fixed now.

```
syntax: regexp
\.(?!java$|class$)[^.]+$
(?<!\.)java$
(?<!\.)class$
```

Comment: Tip: You don't need the leading `.*` (Mercurial does a `search`, not a `match`). A better way of handling 'weird stuff' is `\.(?!java$|class$)[^.]+$` - that is, after rejecting `java` and `class` (thus *not* ignoring those), make sure we're actually looking at the file extension (`[^.]+$`), and not an earlier part of the filename. Finally, you need a separate `^[^.]+$` line to ignore files without an extension.

Comment: @Søren Thanks for the tip. But adding the line `^[^.]+$` makes mercurial ignore text files in subfolders.

Comment: Hm, good point. That's because Mercurial applies ignore patterns to directories as well as files, and since the directory doesn't have a ".java" or ".class" extension, it is ignored. I guess that assuming paths without an extension to be directories is probably the closest thing you get to tell files and directories apart using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If ignored patterns are countable, why not use list of glob patterns? In your case for ignoring everywhere in repo-tree all *.class  and *.java (if I understand task correctly) .hgrc will be

```
syntax: glob

**.class
**.java
```

If you want ignore all files with a lot of (or possible unknown at all) extensions except some you can try to use filesets (`hg help filesets`) in files-definition. Ignoring all extensions except *.png for your case will be smth. like (TBT!)

```
"set:not **.png"
```

Comment: What will putting the first code snippet in my `.hgrc` do? Only accept does files? Should that file be in my working directory?

Comment: First .hgrc example will effectively **ignore (for all repo-related operations) two extensions** of fileson the whole repo-tree. All others extensions for files will be monitored and changes detected. .hgrc usually is versioned file placed in the root-dir of repo

Comment: I think that you misunderstood my question (or I who misunderstood your answer). I want to ignore all files **except** those mentioned above. Your first example describes the opposite from what I want to do.

Furthermore, I could probably use some option from the filesets, and then use something like `hg add "set: not *.class, not *.java"`, to only allow those file extensions to be added, but it would be better to have that option added to my `.hgignore` file for my current project, if possible.

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Ignore **all except two** extensions in .hgignore will be (I Think, TBT) "set:not **.class and not **.java"