# Adding Files That Are Ignored To Git Remote Repository Only Once

Tags: git

Whenever I add ignored files (for instance if I have examplefolder/* in my ignore file and I want to push only one file in that folder up to the remote repo) it will add the file and then push to the repo, but when someone else pulls the updated code they will have to go through the same process of forcing those files to be tracked. Is there any way around adding files more than once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand, there are files in your .gitignore that are also in the repo? It sounds like you are not using .gitignore correctly

Comment: Suppose you want to add only one file in a folder that is ignored, how would you represent that in the gitignore then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803689/gitignore-ignore-all-files-in-folder-hierachy-except-one-specific-filetype